# Remove Space in Asp.Net new project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I started a new project with Asp.Net MVC and wondered how to remove/lower this margin. I added 2 pictures in order to see it.

[image]

[image]

I am pretty new to Asp.Net. Does somebody know how to lower the space?

Comment: If you use the inspect element tool from the browser dev tools you'll be able to see what's generating that sapce. Then you can target that particular element accordingly. Also you have `hr` tag which is usually used to separate content, you could remove it and see what happens

Comment: You seem to be new to `HTML` rather than `ASP.NET`. You can use w3shools website to learn these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio ASP.NET default project template used Bootstrap.
Override the width or remove the container class from your body-content.

Bootstrap use this trick to center the element https://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/451668

```
.container {
    /* first set a width that is smaller then the view */
    width: /* ...px */;
}

.container {
    /* and then set the left and right margin to auto to dynamically calc the same space left and right from the container */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Future reading: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container